# MySQL procedure with insert and update

Tags: mysql

I need some help to create a procedure in MySQL.

I have two tables:

1. connection
2. connection_temporary

And I want to create a procedure that does:

- If `SELECT keyname FROM connection WHERE keyname NOT IN (SELECT keyname FROM connection_temporary)` ***update connection.connection_status to offline***
- If `SELECT keyname FROM connection_temporary WHERE keyname NOT IN (SELECT keyname FROM CONNECTION)` ***insert in connection with connection_temporary's row content***
- If `SELECT keyname, real_ip, virtual_ip, received_bytes, sent_bytes, connection_tstamp FROM connection_temporary WHERE keyname IN (SELECT keyname FROM CONNECTION)` ***update connection with connection_temporary's row content***

How can I do this?

Comment: `SET some_var = (SELECT keyname, real_ip, virtual_ip, received_bytes, sent_bytes, connection_tstamp FROM connection_temporary WHERE keyname IN (SELECT keyname FROM CONNECTION));`

Comment: Inside a procedure. But I don't know how I can do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You should post the schema of your two tables, though, you can do some try by yourself based on following:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `proc`()
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    UPDATE `connection`
    SET `connection`.connection_status = 'offline'
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 
        FROM connection_temporary
        WHERE connection_temporary.keyname = `connection`.keyname
    );

    INSERT INTO `connection` (keyname, real_ip, virtual_ip, received_bytes, sent_bytes, connection_tstamp)
    SELECT keyname, real_ip, virtual_ip, received_bytes, sent_bytes, connection_tstamp
    FROM connection_temporary
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM `connection`
        WHERE connection_temporary.keyname = `connection`.keyname
    );

    UPDATE `connection`
    JOIN connection_temporary ON connection_temporary.keyname = `connection`.keyname
    SET `connection`.keyname = connection_temporary.keyname
    ,`connection`.real_ip = connection_temporary.real_ip
    ,`connection`.virtual_ip = connection_temporary.virtual_ip
    ,`connection`.received_bytes = connection_temporary.received_bytes
    ,`connection`.sent_bytes = connection_temporary.sent_bytes
    ,`connection`.connection_tstamp = connection_temporary.connection_tstamp; 
END
$$ DELIMITER ;
```